# error org-meta-line invalid face

Tags: org-mode

I wanted to customize org-meta-line to make the source code headers look smaller, I'm using this line:

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-meta-line nil :height 0.5 :slant
 'normal :foreground "#C0C0C0" )
```

as mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27470/17618)

it looks like this:

[image: org source]

but I get this error when my init.el is being loaded:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading 
‘/home/kronolynx/.emacs.d/init.el’:

error: Invalid face, org-meta-line
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: running `(set-face-attribute 'org-meta-line ...)` works fine in scratch, Is it possible that in your configuration file the `'org-meta-line` is not declared at that point in the code?  (try to move it forward..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `(set-face-attribute 'org-meta-line ...)` works fine in scratch.

It doesn't in your configuration file because the variable `'org-meta line` is not defined at that point in the code.

The solution will be to move it forward, where org is already required.